# Bulk Insert import data by skipping multiple records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I used bulk insert command to import CSV file to table. I ran the command and it successfully inserted records. When i checked the table where i found only 10 records where as file contains 24 records.

Comment: Someone would be more able to help you if you provide your input and what records were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Simple use
BULK INSERT <tablename>             --  dbo.Orders
FROM        <file path and name>    -- 'c:\temp\orders.txt'
WITH        (
                DATAFILETYPE        = 'char',
                FIELDTERMINATOR     = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR       = '\n'      -- !!! CHECK ALL LINES IN THE FILE HAS IT !!!
            )
;
```

Comment: you are probably missing line terminators, usually CR/LF.